# MacBook Pro constantly freezing/pausing for fractions of a second

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, performance, adobe-flash

I've got a 2008 MacBook Pro (Late 2008/Unibody, MB471LL/A, MacBookPro5,1, A1286) with 6GB of memory and a 160GB OCZ Vertex 2 SSD running 10.6.7 (1OJ869). Around a month ago I noticed the machine is constantly freezing all the time for a fraction of a second, it's really regular and barely noticeable in general use. It's more obvious when scrolling down a long page in Safari (5.0.5) but really noticeable when playing YouTube clips, there's constant pauses. The odd thing is that video played by VLC (1.1.9) is totally smooth. I'm thinking it might be a Flash (10.3 r181) thing as it seems Safari-bound.

I can provide any diag information if anyone would like to help me out (ps -a, top etc. just ask). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions about lion are currently off-topic

Comment: Sorry, typo - not lion at all, I meant 10.**6**.7 not 10.7

Comment: Reopened the question.

Comment: Undoing some injustice :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EXACTLY that symptoms had my friend, he noticed it mostly in Excel an in the gaming - random freezing, first about a half second, later (1-2 months) became worse between 0,5-30 sec.

It was a HW problem. He bring his notebook to apple service, something (don't remember what) got changed and everything is OK now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It was the motherboard. Check the serial, Apple did replace (for free) a whole bunch of boards because of a failure.

Answer (score 1):

Strange as it may sound, it could be the SSD. I have an OCZ Vertex 2 in my MacBookPro7,1 (2010 13") and I discovered that something in iStat Menus was causing disk I/O to stop for a few seconds every now and then. This would manifest itself not by completely freezing the system, but things like when launching apps the icon would bounce and bounce until the I/O resumed, and Chrome would refuse to open new tabs. I got around this by disabling the CPU and sensors widgets in iStat and I haven't had any problems, but there could be a similar app on your system that is causing the problem.

Comment: Very interesting, I have iStat too, I will remove it - I never look at it anyway to be honest - thanks.